# How to make a sin(x) graph function on overleaf

Tags: diagrams

Can somebody please help me on how to make a sin(x) function on overleaf. Domain: -8pi to 8pi

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the package pgfplots?

Comment: Please have a look at pgfmanual before asking for help https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is not overleaf specific question. For drawing of function is essential used package `tikz`, `pgfplots, `pstricks`  etc) for drawing. Code you can write on overleaf (and compile there) but the same code also work for example in MIkTeX, TeXlive, macTeX ...

Answer (score 1):

I have this one alreay used for some project. Should give you a headstart:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=.8\textwidth, height=5cm,
            domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=50,smooth,
            ymin=-1, ymax=1,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=left,
            xtick = {-6.283, -3.145, 0, 3.1415, 6.283},
            xticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, 0, $\pi$, $2\pi$},
            grid = major, ymajorgrids = false,
            x tick label style={black},
            enlarge y limits=.15, enlarge x limits=0]
            \addplot[mark=none]{sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you have follow-up questions make sure you read the pgf manual linked in the [Black Mild's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575618/how-to-make-a-sinx-graph-function-on-overleaf#comment1449531_575618) before asking here.